# How to make this menu behavior in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So this is what i want, take a look jsfiddle for example, I want 3 boxes and when you hover over them another box appears that goes away when you hover away from that box or main box but not when your mouse is in between them the empty space.

Once you click the new box the box remains there until:

- user clicks anywhere else.
- or an close text is clicked

http://jsfiddle.net/T5QHn/4/ **Updated**

```
var menu = $('.menu'), body = $('body');
menu.children('.box').hide();

body.click(hideIt);
menu.hover(showIt,hideIt);
menu.click(keepIt);



function showIt() {
    $(this).children('.box').stop().fadeIn();
}


function keepIt() {
    //something efficent and not illogical..
}


function hideIt() {
    //i have a feeling this depends on keepIt and insn't just inverse of showIt
     $(this).children('.box').stop().fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: same thing as below but with data attribute http://jsfiddle.net/fsPd3/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` on the parent, instead of hover.

Apply the click to hide all boxes to the body, then, on the containers put a click handler with `event.stopPropagation`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/moagrius/fsPd3/1/

Comment: how using those two are going to help instead of hover, and doesn't stopPropagation on click becomes useless when hideIt is fired for mouseleave

Comment: @MuhammadUmer mouseenter/leave will only fire when the mouse pointer leaves the container, not when it leaves a child.  you'll need to manage your handlers (remove mouseenter/leave on click, etc) manually.

Comment: it's same thing that i posted

Comment: @MuhammadUmer it's not even close to what you posted.  click the link i provided, not your original link.  it does everything you asked.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer my mistaked, i forgot to hit update...  http://jsfiddle.net/moagrius/fsPd3/1/